# node.js output special symbols replaced with question mark

Tags: php, node.js, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using a node.js API named notams.js to obtain a list of notices related with Aviation. A PHP script calls the API with the following code:

```
<?php
shell_exec("node notams.js");
?>
```

The notams.js API looks like this:

```
var notams = require("notams");
notams(['LICZ'], { format: 'ICAO' }).then(results => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
});
```

Part of the output looks like this:

V0038/18 NOTAMN : [US DOD PROCEDURAL NOTAM] STANDARD INSTRUMENT DEPARTURE (SID) AMENDMENT RADAR DEPARTURE RWY 28L; TAKE-OFF RWY 28L: CLIMB HEADING 276�.

The question mark replaces the degrees (°) symbol. Any way how to prevent this from happening with any other output? I want the correct symbols to show up.

P.S. the php/html page has the following meta parameters: name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="UTF-8"

Comment: What the character encoding of the input file? Presumably it's not UTF-8, so this is good to figure out. If you know the exact bytes used to encode that symbol, I can probably find it for you.

Comment: I don't know the amount of bytes used to encode the symbol. Can you please explain to me how to get the amount?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the number of bytes to encode that symbol is 3.

Comment: im not talking about amounts. Figure out the exact values. Maybe with `hexdump -C` or some other hex tool

Comment: Did a hexdump.....the value is: ef bf bd

Comment: Ok since that's the case, then when you are outputting the input data is already corrupted. Those valeus are the 'unicode replacement'. The best thing would be to hexdump the actual file where the symbols appear.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but I did a hexdump on the text from the website from where the API is getting the data. Copied and texted the text into a .txt file, did a hexdump on the .txt file and got this: 0000-00f0:  42 20 48 45-41 44 49 4e-47 0d 0a 20-32 37 36 b0  B.HEADIN G...276.
0000-0100:  2e 20 43 52-4f 53 53 20-53 49 47 20-54 41 43 41  ..CROSS. SIG.TACA

Comment: did another hexdump, this time on the ° only, copied from the sourcecode itself....returned: 22 f8 22 20 0a

Comment: Hi Vanny, interestingly this is _also_ wrong. It's the replacement character. So I'm assuming that when you copypasted, you already messed up.

Comment: Edit: it's not the replacement character, but definitely still wrong :(. I looked at some other character encoding tables as well, and I couldn't find a match. Anyway, why are you bothering with this anyway? Just copy paste the symbol (°) in a file and make sure your editor is saving it as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You use shell_exec command in script and I am preaty sure that question mark is result of console encoding / env (eg: like LOCALE=C or other non UTF-8 encoding).

Probably solution will be putting this

```
$locale = 'en_US.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);
```

before `shell_exec("node notams.js");` line.

Comment: Tried this code. Did not work. Are you sure that's the correct syntax?

Comment: I am sure that this code set env variable LC_ALL, I've tested it. I'm sure that problem is in result encoding, but may be this `$programResult = shell_exec("node notams.js");
$programResult = utf8_encode($programResult);` is your solution.

Comment: Now we're talking! I tried utf8_encode and instead of question marks, I've got "ï¿½".

Comment: Okay. Not working, but it's direction. Try `iconv` result conversion. May be UTF-16 -> UTF-8 or UCS BE / LE.

Comment: And I found in ECMA script spec / string data type (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4) they were represented using UTF-16.

Comment: Tried the code: iconv("UTF-16","UTF-8",(shell_exec("node notams.js"))); Didn't work though...

Comment: Well. I'm sure where problem is, but my suggested solutions didn't work. May be someone else will have an idea how to solve it.